# In Django admin options for model like ADD/DELETE/UPDATE not showing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use Django rest framework. After run python manage.py runserver if I open http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ then attached below image showing same

[image]

If I open any model then options like ADD/DELETE/UPDATE options are not showing.
Attached above img for same (user model)

Errors in console showing below-
[image]

**requirement.txt**

```
aiohttp==3.6.3
appdirs==1.4.4
asgiref==3.2.10
async-timeout==3.0.1
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs==20.2.0
awacs==0.9.6
aws-xray-sdk==0.95
awscli==1.20.34
boto3==1.18.32
botocore==1.21.34
certifi==2017.7.27.1
cffi==1.14.3
cfn-flip==1.0.3
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
colorama==0.4.3
colorclass==2.2.0
cryptography==3.1.1
dateparser==0.7.6
defusedxml==0.6.0
dictdiffer==0.7.0
distlib==0.3.1
Django==3.0.9
django-3-jet==1.0.8
django-admin-rangefilter==0.6.3
django-allauth==0.42.0
django-cors-headers==3.6.0
django-extensions==3.0.6
django-filter==2.4.0
django-flat-json-widget==0.1.1
django-grappelli==2.14.2
django-json-widget==1.0.1
django-money==1.1
django-nested-admin==3.3.2
django-otp==1.0.0
django-phonenumber-field==5.0.0
django-prettyjson==0.4.1
django-sendgrid-v5==0.9.0
django-simple-history==2.11.0
django-slack==5.15.3
django-sort-order-field==1.2
django-split-json-widget==1.16
django-storages==1.9.1
django-twilio==0.13.0.post1
djangorestframework==3.11.1
docker==4.3.1
docutils==0.14
ecdsa==0.16.0
filelock==3.0.12
flatten-json==0.1.7
future==0.16.0
futures==3.1.1
idna==2.6
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
jet-bridge-base==0.8.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
jmespath==0.9.3
jsondiff==1.1.1
jsonpickle==1.4.1
jsonschema==2.6.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mock==4.0.2
more-itertools==8.5.0
moto==1.3.7
multidict==4.7.6
oauthlib==3.1.0
phonenumbers==8.12.8
Pillow==7.2.0
pluggy==0.13.1
prompt-toolkit==2.0.9
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
py==1.9.0
py-moneyed==0.8.0
pyaml==20.4.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pycparser==2.20
pycryptodome==3.9.8
PyJWT==1.7.1
pyotp==2.4.0
pytest==4.0.0
python-dateutil==2.6.1
python-dotenv==0.14.0
python-http-client==3.3.1
python-jose==2.0.2
python-monkey-business==1.0.0
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
regex==2020.7.14
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
responses==0.12.0
rsa==4.5
s3transfer==0.5.0
sendgrid==6.4.7
six==1.10.0
slackclient==2.9.2
SQLAlchemy==1.3.19
sqlparse==0.3.1
standardjson==0.3.1
starkbank-ecdsa==1.1.0
stringcase==1.0.6
terminaltables==3.1.0
troposphere==2.6.2
twilio==6.45.0
tzlocal==2.1
urllib3==1.25.10
virtualenv==20.0.31
wcwidth==0.2.5
websocket-client==0.57.0
Werkzeug==1.0.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.1
xmltodict==0.12.0
yarl==1.5.1
zipp==3.2.0
```

I use pyenv for environment.

Comment: It need to `python manage.py collectstatic`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: @MahrusKhomaini Should I run this command before runserver?

Comment: Just run it once before runserver, after that no need again.